# A_ldiv_B! with sparse matrices

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, julia, factorization, levenberg-marquardt

The following lines of code appear in levenberg-marquardt algorithm in the optimization package "Optim":

```
DtD = diagm(Float64[max(x, MIN_DIAGONAL) for x in sum(J.^2,1)])
delta_x = ( J'*J + sqrt(lambda)*DtD ) \ -J'*fcur
```

However, my questions has nothing to do with the algorithm or anything specific to the package. I guess it has more to do with linear algebra and factorization in base julia.

If I have a full matrix J, the following works:

```
In  [3]: n = 5
J = rand(n,n)
fcur = rand(n)
DtD = diagm(Float64[max(x, 1e-6) for x in sum(J.^2,1)])
( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ -J'*fcur

Out [3]: 5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.0740316
 -0.0643279
 -0.0665033
 -0.10568  
 -0.0599613
```

However, if J is sparse, I get an error:

```
In  [4]: J = sparse(J)
DtD = diagm(Float64[max(x, 1e-6) for x in sum(J.^2,1)])
( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ -J'*fcur

Out [4]: ERROR: `A_ldiv_B!` has no method matching A_ldiv_B!(::Cholesky{Float64}, ::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
while loading In[4], in expression starting on line 3

 in \ at linalg/generic.jl:233
```

So as far as I understand (with my limited knowledge of julia as a beginner), this error occurs because julia tries to compute `( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ -J'` first. **My first question is how can I know what path julia is taking when implementing the above code?** I am aware of `@which` but I don't know how to use it to get to A_ldiv_B! as this should start with `\(A,B)` and then somehow end up with A_ldiv_B! :

```
In  [6]: a = ( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ); b = -J'; @which a\b

Out [6]: \(A::Union(SubArray{T,2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:(Union(Range{Int64},Int64)...,)},DenseArray{T,2}),B::Union(SubArray{T,2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:(Union(Range{Int64},Int64)...,)},SubArray{T,1,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:(Union(Range{Int64},Int64)...,)},DenseArray{T,2},DenseArray{T,1})) at linalg/dense.jl:409
```

Also note that:

```
In  [7]: typeof(a)

Out [7]: Array{Float64,2}

In  [8]: typeof(b)

Out [8]: Array{Float64,2}
```

Which makes this even more confusing, as there is no Cholesky type in the above. **My second question is: how does the Cholesky type appear?** The error message says: `A_ldiv_B!` has no method matching A_ldiv_B!(::**Cholesky{Float64}**, ::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})

Another interesting point that I accidentally found was that if the sparse matrix is of size (2,2) the above error does not occur:

```
In  [9]: n = 2
J = sparse(rand(n,n))
fcur = rand(n)
DtD = diagm(Float64[max(x, 1e-6) for x in sum(J.^2,1)])
( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ -J'*fcur

Out [9]: 2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.0397989
 -0.052129
```

Finally, I could solve this problem by putting `-J'*fcur` in parantheses, which seems to be the intention of the author anyway. But I am very confused. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
In  [12]: n = 5
J = sparse(rand(n,n))
fcur = rand(n)
DtD = diagm(Float64[max(x, 1e-6) for x in sum(J.^2,1)])
( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ (-J'*fcur)

Out [12]: 5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.0536266
 -0.0692286
 -0.0673166
 -0.0616349
 -0.0559813
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit tricky to figure out exactly which code path is taken when your are running into code that uses substitutions during parsing as is the case for `'`. You could try 

`julia> ( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ -J'fcur`

to see another substitution taking place.

I don't know if it really is an answer to your question, but I'll note three things about your example.

1. Julia parses from left to right so I think the example should be read like

   `(( J'*J + sqrt(100)*DtD ) \ ctranspose(-J))*fcur`
2. We haven't implemented sparse right hand side in solves because even when `b` in `Ax=b` is sparse then typically the result is not sparse, so the gain from exploiting the sparseness of the `b` is modest.
3. The "right" way of solving the problem is to add the parentheses around `(-Jfcur)` because then the solution is a sparse matrix-vector multiplication and a sparse matrix-vector solve instead of sparse matrix-matrix solve and a dense matrix-vector multiplication.